# ChartJS displays 2 values instead of one in a multi dataset chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to have only one value to be displayed instead of two values, I've tried everything and was following another StackOverflow link but it keeps showing twice, how would I be able to only show the value once?

The code below is what I've tried so far, but I keep getting shown the 2 values, I'm trying to achieve so only 1 value is shown. I'm aware this is a dirty workaround but i don't know any other option.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { tempData } from './LineChartData';

import './LineChart.scss';

type LineChartProps = {
  data?: any;
  options?: any;
};

export const LineChart: React.FC<LineChartProps> = ({ data, options }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('components');

  const chartData = data || tempData;

  let newArray: any = [];

  data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    newArray.push({
      ...dataset,
      pointRadius: 2,
      data: dataset.data.map((item, index) => {
        return index < dataset.data.length - 1 ? item : null;
      }),
    });
    newArray.push({
      ...dataset,
      data: dataset.data,
      pointRadius: 2,
      borderDash: [5, 5],
    });
  });

  let newChartData = { datasets: newArray, labels: data.labels };

  chartData.datasets.map((dataset) => {
    dataset.pointRadius = dataset.pointRadius || 1;
    dataset.label = t(dataset.label);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const Chart = require('react-chartjs-2').Chart;

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Gotham';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="line-chart">
      <Line
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          elements: {
            line: {
              fill: false,
              tension: 0,
            },
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  padding: 20,
                },
                gridLines: {
                  display: false,
                },
              },
            ],
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                  padding: 20,
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
                gridLines: {
                  drawBorder: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          ...options,
        }}
        data={newChartData}
      />

      <ul className="legend">
        {chartData.datasets.map((dataset, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <span
              style={{ backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor }}
              className="legend-color"
            ></span>
            {dataset.label}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTfro.jpg)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkhpc.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a reprodusable sample. Because when I try it normally with your options it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/xf2ej3a7/2/